# How to change SharePoint Mysite Quota for a particular user only?

Tags: sharepoint-server, mysite

I want to change the storage quota for particular user only.

For example I have 200 users where by default user will get 100 MB as per individual quota template but for particular users this can be 500MB or 1GB....

Answer (score 1):

To change the quota of an individual user:

- Central Admin > Application Management > **Configure Quotas and Locks**
- Select the user's mysite as the Site Collection
- Change the Current Quota template to **Individual Quota** and set the values manually

Comment: But this will provide storage of all users, I want to increase quota for say single person like if 200 users then only user 1 will have 500mb other will have default as per the quota template.

Comment: You limit changes to just that one persons quota by selecting the specific person's mySite from the Site Collections.